Google OAuth Redirects to /login/oauth2/code/google Instead of My Custom Success Handler URL
I am implementing Google OAuth login for my Spring Boot application, and I am facing an issue with redirection after a successful login.
Homepage URL: https://www.codebyte.work/
Desired Redirect URL After Login:
https://www.codebyte.work/courses?accessToken=<token>&refreshToken=<token>

Authorized JavaScript Origins in Google Console: https://www.codebyte.work
Authorized Redirect URIs in Google Console: https://www.codebyte.work/login/oauth2/code/google
My OAuth2SuccessHandler Class:
    @Component
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class OAuth2SuccessHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {
        private final UserEntityService userService;
        private final JwtService jwtService;
    
        @Override
        public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
            OAuth2AuthenticationToken token = (OAuth2AuthenticationToken) authentication;
            DefaultOAuth2User OAuthUser = (DefaultOAuth2User) token.getPrincipal();
    
            String email = OAuthUser.getAttribute("email");
            UserEntity user = userService.getUserByEmail(email);
            if (user == null) {
                user = userService.save(
                    UserEntity.builder()
                              .name(OAuthUser.getAttribute("name"))
                              .email(email)
                              .roles(Set.of(Roles.USER))
                              .build()
                );
            }
    
            String accessToken = jwtService.generateAccessJwtToken(user);
            String refreshToken = jwtService.generateRefreshJwtToken(user);
    
            Cookie cookie = new Cookie("refreshToken", refreshToken);
            cookie.setHttpOnly(true);
            cookie.setPath("/");
            response.addCookie(cookie);
    
            // Redirecting to the frontend with tokens
            String frontEndUrl = "https://www.codebyte.work/courses?accessToken=" + accessToken
                    + "&refreshToken=" + refreshToken;
            getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, frontEndUrl);
        }
    }

Web Security Configuration:
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    @EnableMethodSecurity
    @RequiredArgsConstructor
    public class WebSecurityConfigs {
        private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
        private final OAuth2SuccessHandler successHandler;
    
        @Bean
        SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests(auth -> auth
                    .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/home.html").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .oauth2Login(oauth2 -> oauth2
                    .successHandler(successHandler)
                );
            return http.build();
        }
    }

application.properties Configuration:
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=your-client-id
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=your-client-secret
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.redirect-uri=https://www.codebyte.work/login/oauth2/code/google

The Problem:
When I log in with Google, instead of being redirected to my desired URL (https://www.codebyte.work/courses?accessToken=<token>&refreshToken=<token>), the application redirects to:
https://www.codebyte.work/login/oauth2/code/google?state=...&code=...&scope=...

This triggers my custom "Page Not Found" error page, which is designed to show if someone tries to access any non-existing endpoint.
I have verified that:
Client ID and Client Secret: Correctly configured in application.properties.
Authorized Redirect URI in Google Console: Matches the application configuration.
OAuth2SuccessHandler: Is registered in WebSecurityConfigs.
What I Need:
How can I ensure the application redirects to my custom URL ([https://www.codebyte.work/courses][1]) after a successful login instead of showing the "Page Not Found" error page?
You can refer to the below images for more details about the issue:
Any guidance or suggestions would be appreciated.


Based on your description, I don't see any issues in my local. Could you provide a minimal sample that reproduces the steps? I'd be happy to take a look.

for my local system it is working as expected also when my front end was hosted over the Vercel app, then also this works as it is. but when I am switching this to my custom domains, this is not working anymore
